# RediSql (for redis): Get column names as well as data type?

Tags: sql, sqlite, redis, redisql

I am using the excellent [RediSql](https://redisql.com/), a module for Redis, to get a powerful caching solution.

When sending a command to Redis, that interacts with the SqLite db in the background, like this:

```
REDISQL.EXEC db "SELECT * FROM jobcache"
```

I get a result like this:

[image]

I get a type for the integer column, but not for the string, and no column names are provided.

Is there a way to get column name and defined data type always? I would need this, as I need to convert the results back to a more standard sql result format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, at the moment this is not possible with the EXEC command.

You can use the `QUERY.INTO command` [reference](https://redisql.redbeardlab.com/rediSQL/references/#redisqlqueryinto)

`QUERY.INTO` add the result of your query into a stream, it adds the column and the values for each row. Then you can consume the stream in whichever way you prefer.

When doing query (reads) against RediSQL is a good practice to use the `.QUERY` family of commands, this avoids useless replication of data, in the case you are in a cluster setup.

Moreover, it is possible to use the `.QUERY` commands also against replica of the main redis instance, while the `.EXEC` commands can be used only against the primary instance.

Comment: Siscia, you also mentioned that v 2 of RediSql might give the option to get column names back, right? =)

Comment: Update: Siscia has resolved this issue and in newer versions, column names are returned to make parsing, and life in general, easier. Good stuff!